# How and when are ext4 metadata checksums checked?

Tags: linux, ext4

I have an ext4 filesystem with metadata checksums (option metadata_csum) enabled. Are the checksums used to verify that data is correct when doing a e2fsck? Is some special flag required? Are they used at any other times or with other tools?